# Spring batch admin not triggering a scheduled task

Tags: spring, spring-batch-admin

```
    @Component
    public class JobScheduler {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JobScheduler.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void run() {
        try {
            String dateParam = new Date().toString();
            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    }
```

The batch job xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.batch.admin.sample" />

<job id="infinite1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet start-limit="100">
            <chunk commit-interval="1" reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.sample.ExampleItemWriter"/>
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.sample.ExampleItemReader" scope="step"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="jobScheduler" method="run" cron="0 0/1 * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="jobScheduler" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.sample.JobScheduler" />
```

I am using the VMWare vFabric tc Server which comes bundled with STS 3.6
The cron expression should have triggered the infinite1 job for every one minute. But it does not. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  If so, what was your solution?

Comment: @Rick - Nope we could not get that to work so we put that in the backlog and moved on to other items.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `@EnableScheduling` in your class

Comment: Using that annotation causes this error: "@Scheduled method 'removeInactiveExecutions' found on bean target class 'SimpleJobService' but not found in any interface(s) for a dynamic proxy."  Even when using annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true), still get same error.

Using SBA 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and Spring Batch Core 3.0.7.RELEASE